# Change value object Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a normal object in javascript, contenting functions and values.

This is my example object:

```
var MyObject = {
    myData: 1,
    a: function() {},
    b: function() {}   
}
```

Now in the function `a` there is some logic that fire on it, but it should change even the value of `myData` property.

But when i try get it from the method `b`, that value come as an undefined value, instead of the value changed.

I created a **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xaaLQ/2/)** with a small example of the behaviour of the my object. I realized that it how Javascript behave, but I didn't understand why.

Comment: It's probably the scope

Comment: `this` reference is not carried over into your event handlers. You need to assign it to another variable outside the handlers and access it through the closure, `var self = this;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because `this` within the click handlers refers to the element which was clicked, not the object the handler functions are members of. You need to cache `this`:

```
a: function () {
    var self = this;
    $('.setValue').click(function() {
        self.myData = 2;
    });
},
b: function () {
    var self = this;
    $('.getValue').click(function() {
        alert(self.myData);
    });
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xaaLQ/3/)

Comment: Thanks :) just waiting a couples of minutes to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, each function has its own `this` argument. In your case, you want to access the outer function's this variable so you should do something like this:

```
var that = this;
```

Here is the updated jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/xaaLQ/5/